# Nginx throwing 502 Bad Gateway on blog (subdomain)

Tags: php, nginx

So, I was trying to setup `mysite.com/blog` initially, but got pretty fed up with it, so i setup `blog.mysite.com` instead.

It successfully loads the index file: `index.htm`, but if i try to access a file `info.php` it fails saying: `502 bad gateway`, i checked `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and it says:

> 2016/12/17 09:24:13 [error] 1042#0: *4 connect() failed (111:
>   Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: x.xx.xx.xx,
>   server: blog.mysite.com, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "blog.mysite.com"

I installed php via: `sudo apt-get install php5-fpm php5-mysql` from this tutorial: [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04)

My nginx config in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myblog` is:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root /home/www/flask-deploy/myblog;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name blog.mysite.com www.blog.mysite.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your nginx config has a bad path to php-fpm.sock. (Your error.log is right ;) )

1. What version of PHP are you using? Use:

`php -v`

2. Make sure that **php-fpm** is installed, it is very important for nginx.

`sudo apt-get install php-fpm`

3. Set correct path to php-fpm

For example, I use **PHP7.0** and my path is:

`fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;`

Some my projects are running on **PHP5.6** and path is:

`fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;`

4. Restart nginx and php-fpm (php5.6-fpm, php7.0-fpm...)

`sudo service nginx restart`

`sudo service php5.6-fpm restart`

Comment: how do i tell the php version?

Comment: how do i install php5? i installed via `sudo apt-get install php5-fpm php5-mysql` but `php -v` says it doesnt have php

Comment: So try command: **which php** 
It will tell you where is php installed. Output should looks like: /usr/bin/php
try to run: /usr/bin/php -v

Comment: unfortunately it shows nothing. i ran `locate php` and i saw a lot of things, one being: `/var/lib/php5/modules/fpm`. i also updated my code, and error above, thoughts?

Comment: try this tutorial: [link](http://tecadmin.net/install-php5-on-ubuntu/) . Follow instructions for PHP5.6. Be sure there is no errors while installing.

Comment: Do you think php5 is currently installed? Is this fpm php - `/usr/sbin/php5-fpm` ?

Comment: btw this link you provided tries to install apache when i am using nginx

Comment: I have **php5.6** installed now

Comment: Good job, I edited my answer, follow step 4 it should work now

Comment: `sudo service php5.6-fpm restart `results in a `unrecognized service`

Comment: Is it installed? `sudo apt-get install php5.6-fpm` ?

Comment: IT WORKS! You made my weekend! Thank you so much!

Comment: Pointed me into the right direction, turned out my php7.0 was located at /var/run/ *php* /php7.0-fpm.sock; forgot the extra *php* folder